# A reference taking function with a default value

Tags: c++

Consider this function:

```
void func(int* a = nullptr)
{
    if (a)
        *a = 1;
}
```

I can then call function without the parameter, as it has the default value (`func()`) or I can obtain a value via the parameter (`func(somePtr)`).
Now I was trying to figure out either the same functionality is possible to accomplish without method overloading with references. The closest thing I got was utilizing an universal reference, but in this case I am bound to using template types and in my case my type is strict. Is there a way to translate this bare pointer functionality to references functionality?

One way of doing this I came up with is:

```
void func(int& a)
{
     a = 5;
}

void func()
{
     int dummy;
     fund(dummy);
}
```

I am aiming for something like this (wont work):

```
template<typename T>
void func(T&& a = int())
{
     a = 1;
}
```

Comment: References are non-null, by definition. Unlike pointers, references are always bound to objects.

Comment: I know, thats why I though ubiversal reference could come to the resque, since it can be bound to rvalues, which could be created by default.

Comment: Hmm ... can you show the motivation though?  I am fine with `void func(T* = nullptr)`, or even just `T func()` since we have guaranteed copy elision since C++17.

Comment: If you have a reference parameter then there is no `if(a)` possibility (references are always bound)

Comment: and do you want to be able to call the function with rvalue argument (.e.g `func(2+2)`), and what should the behaviour of the function be in that case? It has no observable behaviour here (and in the `func()` version too).

Comment: Its just an MWE. In reality the int is some custom type. I am just wondering either such functionality is possible to accomplish without method overloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overloading is the most natural way, e.g.

```
void func(int&  a)  {  a = 1; /* assume some other complex logic here */ }
void func(int&& a = int())  { func(a); }
```

It is possible to make the SFINAE version work, although I'm sure aesthetic views will differ:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename U>
using EnableIfSame = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>, U>>;

template<typename T = int, typename = EnableIfSame<T, int>>
void func(T&& a = int())
{
    a = 1;
}
```

If you don't have C++17 then `is_same_v<Z>` would need to be replaced with `is_same<Z>::value`, and if not C++14 then `enable_if_t<Z>` with `typename enable_if<Z>::type` .

Comment: It was more of a question either it is possible, aesthetics were not so important. Just to let you know, I am using C++14 and `is_same_v` is available. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I could figure out your problem. Maybe this method answers your question.

```
void *p;

template <typename T>
void func(T def, T& t = *(T *)p)
{
    if (&t != p)
        t = def;
}

int main()
{
    int a;
    func(1);
    func(1, a);
}
```